# Django: passing variable to simple_tag other than id fails

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-custom-tags

Situation is simple: I want to show a specific object (model Block) in a template like this: `{% block_by_name editorial as b %} {{ b.title }}` or, preferably with a filter like this `{{ block.title|get_by_name:editorial }}`.

I succeeded with a simple_tag.

#### Getting items by id works fine:

```
# in templatetags
@register.simple_tag
def block_by_id(id=1):
    b = Block.objects.get(id=id)
    return b


# in html template it get block with id 3 and shows it OK
{% block_by_id 3 as b %} {{ b.title }}
```

However, when I want to get blocks by names or tags like below,

#### Getting items by name fails

```
#
@register.simple_tag
def block_by_name(n="default_name"):
    b = Block.objects.get(name=n)
    return b

# in html template it fails to get block with name "editorial"
{% block_by_name editorial as b %} {{ b.title }}
```

Django shows the error `Block matching query does not exist`
Because it assumes that variable `n` is empty string, though I passed it: "editorial"

The traceback:

```
        b = Block.objects.get(name=n)

     ...

▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
n
```

''

Not sure why this happens.
How can I pass the variable so as it does not disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you didn't pass `"editorial"`, you passed `editorial`. That's a variable, which does not exist. Use the string.

Comment: Thanks! I was so following the path of IDs 1, 2, 3 which required no quotes.